# Flow DepartLane definition exception

Tags: flow-project

After running many episodes of the same environment, I often get this error telling me the departLane definition is invalid:

> Error: Answered with error to command 0xc4: Invalid departLane
>   definition for vehicle 'host_0';  must be one of ("random", "free",
>   "allowed", "best", "first", or an int>=0)

I've tried debugging it and yet I never send any value which is not permitted (mainly just add vehicles with departLane=0).
Does it have to do with something else than the departLane itself?

Comment: Some bad input data. Our guess is wild, you can look at it...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `departLane=0` may not exist in your code.

Could you try "random" or "free" and see if it works?